# How to configuration projectId in pom.xml When using two project google cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform

I have developed spring boot application and create a cloud build pipeline in GCP.

In My pom.xml, How to configure dynamic projectId, because I have two project in GCP.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
<configuration>
<deploy.projectId>project1</deploy.projectId>
<deploy.version>4</deploy.version>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Which library are you using? As an example with App Engine you can specify project Id as flag `mvn package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=PROJECT_ID`, this will overwrite one from `pom.xml`

Comment: I am using Cloud Build in GCP, where I can set dynamic project Id, Can I set cloudbuild.yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy your app to App Engine with dynamic Project Ids, run the following command from your project's top level directory, where the `pom.xml` file is located:

`mvn package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=PROJECT_ID`

If you specify your Project id in the `pom.xml` file this Project id will be defined as the default project, I suggest to remove it from this file and specify the project everytime you deploy your app.

You can obtain more information on the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/uploadinganapp#deploying_an_app)

Comment: I am using Cloud Build in GCP, where I can set dynamic project Id, Can I set cloudbuild.yaml file?

Comment: You can write the build config file using the YAML or the JSON syntax, you can get further information about  the structure of a build config file in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#structure_of_a_build_config_file)